# How To Use Isolates in Flutter for functions which are inside a class

Tags: flutter

I am currently implementing a camera screen in which i am using the camera package to capture live streams which i am then passing on to firebase for text detection.

The problem is when the application is run on a single thread it throws error that it skipped frames and that too much work was being done on a single thread. Now, when i tried to do multiple threading using isolates the function does not get executed because it is inside a class and i cannot take my function out of the class because according to the documentation the camera controller has to be initialised inside a init state.

Comment: did you try using `async`?

Comment: i already tried that